# Changing selection resolution for component properties

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Using the viewer, we can interact with the model browser to change the selection resolution in order to see different properties about a selected component.  However, for most of our users, this is incredibly unintuitive.  Is there a programmatic way to set the selection resolution used by the viewer's built in properties window so that we can control what properties are displayed when a user selects a component in the viewer? Or maybe there is a better way that is intended to allow developers to control which properties are shown within the viewer's built in properties window?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own property panel that will allow you to pass in the desired properties you want your users to see. I have done this in a sample listed below, where I populate in a separate table, not using the Viewer Toolbar, the different categories for the properties of the model. Try the Revit House model.

https://viewer-rocks.autodesk.io/

[image]

Also here is another demo where a Meta-properties panel got built that even allows you to modify the properties, remove, add new ones to that panel.

https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5904729b0007f5ead5b1196d

[image]

You can see both source projects from Github.